# Powerpoint 2010 VSTO AddIn taskpane on multiple Windows

Tags: .net, vsto, ms-office, powerpoint, office-addins

I would like have a taskpane displayed on each document-windows, I have read all MSDN articles about it, but it doesn't work.

I click on ToggleButton1 when 3 or 4 document are open, and i get 3 or 4 TaskPanes, but on same document window.

Edit :

I think i don't have correctly explain the problem, sorry.

New try : I click on ToggleButton1 on Presentation 1 window when 3 or 4 document are open, and i get 3 or 4 TaskPanes inside Prestation 1 window, windows from other presentation are empty.

What i want is a shared taskpane and synchronized visibility accross all presentations

**ThisAddin.vb**

```
Public Class ThisAddin

    Public Sub Test()
        For Each w As PowerPoint.DocumentWindow In Application.Windows

            Me.CustomTaskPanes.Add(New UserControl1, "abc", w).Visible = True

        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Ribbon1.vb**

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles ToggleButton1.Click

    Globals.ThisAddIn.test()

End Sub
```

I also have tried with :

```
For Each w As PowerPoint.Presentation In Application.Presentations
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerPoint, the task panes are [shared across all document windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#CustomTaskPaneBehavior). As you switch between presentation windows, the same task pane is used (*this is why you get 3 or 4 panes when you add task panes for each window - they are shared across presentations*). If you want separate task panes you need to open/close the active task panes (*or separately manage task pane state per presentation*) as you change the active `DocumentWindow`

Comment: My apologies, the problem was not correctly explained. I think despite the AddIn is shared across presentations, they are on another thread. That's why put the test function on AfterPresentationOpen works since i am in the good thread ?

Comment: You just need to make the other custom task panes hidden.

Comment: Yes, this is a solution, all presentation get 1 taskpane, and i change visibility like i want. But now the thing is to create and release customtaskpane correctly

Comment: I'm not sure that SliverNinja is correct here, as the title refers to PowerPoint 2010, and this version now supports inidividual document windows per presentation as [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb608620(v=vs.100).aspx#WordAndInfoPath)