# PowerPoint 2010 Custom TaskPane in multple windows

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, powerpoint, office-addins

I am developing a custom task pane for Microsoft PowerPoint 2010. I need the task pane to be synchronized between multiple application windows/presentations. The task panes are displayed using a toggle button on the ribbon.

Since PowerPoint 2010 displays each presentation in a different document window (which is different from 2007), I need to create a task pane separately for each window and synchronize them. I have followed the [Microsoft tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264456.aspx) on how to create task panes for multiple application windows, and I am using the [`CustomTaskPaneCollection.Add(UserControl, String, Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa941973.aspx) method to specify which application window the task pane should be associated with. In this case the `Object` is the `PowerPoint.DocumentWindow` that the task pane should be associated with.

For some reason all of my task panes are created in the active window and not the window that I assign. For example, if I open 3 PowerPoint presentations and then toggle the task pane, all three task panes will be added to the active window.

This is the code I am using to add the task panes when the toggle is pressed:

```
public void AddAllTaskPanes()
{
   PowerPoint.DocumentWindows windows = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Windows;
   if(windows.Count > 0)
   {
      for (int i=1; i<=windows.Count; i++){
         PowerPoint.DocumentWindow window = windows[i];
         customTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new UserControl1(), "My User Control", window);
         customTaskPane.Visible = true;
      }
   }
}
```

It seems that this should successfully add each task pane to its specified `window`, and I cannot figure out why all of the task panes are being associate with the active window instead. I have done a lot of research into this issue and have not been able to find a solution. The closest I have found was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726030/powerpoint-2010-vsto-addin-taskpane-on-multiple-windows), however the answer corresponds to PowerPoint 2007 and not 2010 like the question references.

Any insight into why PowerPoint may be behaving this way would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I went the way of creating the TaskPanes from the PresentationAfterOpen and PresentationAfterNew Events which produces the same behaviour.

A note about the  PresentationAfterOpen event, if the document selected by the user is already open, the event is still fired so you need to check if the CustomTaskPane has already been created for that document before creating a new one.

A way to overcome this problem is to create a pointer to the associated DocumentWindow in your CustomPane and enumerate through the CustomTaskPaneCollection checking for the associated one.